# How do I identify an SR SunTour fork exact model?

Tags: parts, fork

I recently located this SR SunTour [service manual](http://srsuntour-files.dbap.de/_public/tuningbase/downloadarea/catalogs/SRSuntour_Workshop_Book.pdf), containing schematics of a load of forks. Trouble is, my fork only has "XCR" on a sticker, and production date stamped.

At some [forum](http://forums.mtbr.com/shocks-suspension/confused-about-low-end-suntour-suspension-forks-640272.html) this is discussed and links are provided to SunTour's XCM, XCR and XCR product lines. Strangely, my XCR does not match visually any of the presented (mine has no V-brake option).

**Am I supposed to find a model number stamped *somewhere* on the fork**, as with most other bicycle components, or should I deduce which fork it is from the features e.g. wheel size, brake options, outlook, locking and adjustment mechanisms.

I would be quite surprised if the model is not stamped. How do bicycle mechanics deduce the model - do they know them all from experience?

Comment: What about the barcode or numbers available on the forks do they help??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Suntour's [XCR page](http://www.srsuntour-cycling.com/dstore/products/Suspension+Fork/2888/XCR/SF11-XCR+LO+26%27.html) you'll find some pictures of forks that have both disc and v-brake mounts. However if you press "Show more details" you can read on the bottom of the details column: "Note Disc only type bottom case available". The same model can have two different bottom cases which support disc and v-brake or just disc mounts.

I also have an XCR and the model is nowhere to be found. You have to try and deduce the model.

Comment: Observations: 1. (probably) all spring-equipped Suntour forks have v-brake and no-vbrake options 2. the only differences are travel and lockout option. 3. The best low-end fork is the one with long travel and **no lockout**. It is both the ceepest and the most smooth, as **the springs are 2, not only 1**.

Answer (score 2):

The fork should have a serial number. Not obvious and a little small and faint, something like tb0111xxxx. Mine was located on the lower assembly.

Go to https://www.srsuntour-cycling.com/service/ enter the number and it should come back with model type and year of manufacture. From that you should be able to find the exploded view pdf.

Answer (score 0):

A easier way may be to look up your bike year and model on [bikepedia](http://Bikepedia.com), the site is both detailed and accurate.