# What is Speed Lockout on a SUNTOUR fork?

Tags: fork

Looking at entry level SR SunTour suspension forks, there are the options of

- "MLO" - mechanical lockout
- "HLO" - hydraulic lockout
- "RL" - remote lockout

Now, mechanical and hydraulic lockout is clear. Remote lockout - not so much - it says that it is engaged from the handlebars, not from the fork itself.

My forks says [XCR 011 Series mg](http://velosipedidani.com/suntour-xcr-011-series-p-5539.html). On the side of the knob is written "Speed lockout". I am able to lock the fork while compressed, but if I do it uncompressed, there is some small damping still, which is very nice.

How do I know what is this "Speed lockout" thing, without disassembling the fork.

[Note that I have been unable to identify the exact model of the fork.](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/16472/how-do-i-identify-an-sr-suntour-fork-exact-model)

Comment: hey does anybody know if a hydraulic lockout can be used with a remote? like if a bicycle has an option of remote lockout. does that mean the remote has been added to mechanical or hydraulic lockout? its confusing as the remote lockout itself is not a type of lockout but just a remote added to an existing lockout technology like hydraulic or mechanical.
but which one of the two is it is what i wanna know

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remote lockout means that the fork has a "remote" lever that is installed in the handlebar.

My fork is a XCR RL from 2011 as well and pressing the blue lever locks the fork, pressing the black lever on top of the blue unlocks it. This is a XCR from 2011 as well.

You can see the remote in the following picture:

[image: http://postimg.org/image/3quyvjcx3/]

If you have a knob with speed lockout you should have a fork similar to SF11 XCR LO 26". If your fork has rebound adjustment then it's a XCR LOD. You'll have to look that up in Suntour's site since I can't post more than one link.

Browsing Suntour's Tuning Base may give you additional information.

Comment: Yea, it looks very much like the SF11 XCR LO 26". On the SunTour site it is listed as "Hydraulic Speed lock". Does this mean that my lockout is hydraulic for sure?

Comment: Reading the SRSuntour service manuals, they say "every SunTour fork will retain some travel after being lock-out". Also "the patented blowout system is intended to disengage the lockout when a hard enough hit is received (forgetting the fork locked and going downhill.)". Note that those are not exact quotes.

Comment: If the lockout knob is blue, then the lockout must bi hydraulic. But i'm not 100 percent sure about it.